# An authentication issue with WWW::Scripter

Tags: perl, mechanize, www-mechanize

I am using plugin [WWW::Scripter](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW%3a%3aScripter) (subclass of [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/WWW%3a%3aMechanize)) to authenticate to my host's login page. They use `Ruby` with some `JavaScript` functions on the login page, so I can't just use the `LWP::Agent` module. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

use LWP::Debug qw(+);
use LWP::ConnCache;
use WWW::Scripter;

my $url = 'https://control.vp.net/login';
my $username = 'example@example.com';
my $password = 'example';

my $w = WWW::Scripter->new(keep_alive => 1) or die "error1: $!\n";
$w->conn_cache(LWP::ConnCache->new);
$w->use_plugin('JavaScript') or die "error2: $!\n";
$w->credentials($url, undef, $username, $password) or die "error3: $!\n";
$w->get($url) or die "error4: $!\n";
print $w->content() or die "error5: $!\n";
```

I am having the following error:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
error3
```

I have spent number of hours googling and I feel that I really need some of your help now. I will appreciate any help which help to understand why I can't authenticate. My Perl version is 5.10.1 on Ubuntu 11 if it matters.

Thanks.

**Update**

I have changed one line in the code to:

```
$w->credentials($username, $password) or die "error3: $!\n";
```

and getting just white page now. If I enable the diagnostics pragma, a rather general error appears:

```
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at blib/lib/Net/SSLeay.pm
(autosplit into blib/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/randomize.al) line 2227 (#1)
(W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
```

Comment: Try to use `$w->credentials($username, $password)`, no `$url, undef`. Class `WWW::Scripter` is subclass of `WWW::Mechanize`, so see http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm for `credentials` documentation

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have updated my post. Could you please help to troubleshoot the white page?

Comment: Are you using correct `$url`? Temporarily remove line `$w->use_plugin('JavaScript') or die "error2: $!\n";` to find out if you are getting white page as the result of some script from that page, or just because that is a page content.

Comment: Yes, that helped. Now, no any white page, just simple html. I am still not able to authenticate though. As I understand, I should check the HTTP headers of a successful login and try to do same in my code now?

Comment: There may be tens of reason why you got blank response. First, try add user-agent information to look like a real browser. I believe you are getting status 302 and there is some redirect location in http headers in the response you got, so you have to then continue with such new url. Additionally, you might need to add cookies and referer as well, to keep session, etc. Good luck!

Comment: You were absolutely right regarding the redirect 302.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`credentials` is good for [standard HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), but Web forms are something different. Remove that method call and learn how Web forms function. The JavaScript has no influence on the Web form, Mechanize is enough.

```
use strictures;
my ($url, $username, $password)
    = qw(https://control.vps.net/login example@example.com example);
my $w = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$w->get($url);  # automatically raises exception on HTTP errors
$w->submit_form(with_fields => {
    'session[email_address]' => $username,
    'session[password]' => $password,
});
die 'login failed'
    if $w->content =~ /your email and password combination were incorrect/;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't simply expect every function to return a truthy value on success and a falsy value on failure like that.

The [entry for `credentials`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Ecredentials%28_%24username,_%24password_%29), for example, says nothing about what it returns, so you shouldn't attempt to do anything with whatever it returns.

Same goes for [`get`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Eget%28_%24uri_%29) - it returns a response object, which will presumably always be true.

You need to call all of the functions and then check [`$w->status()`](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm#%24mech-%3Estatus%28%29).  If it returns 401 or 403 then authentication failed.

Comment: I've tried adding the method status after each line but it does not unfortunately show any error number.

Comment: `status()` is only valid after a call to `get()`.

Comment: If OP gets response, status has to be okay.

Comment: Mech automatically raises exceptions, see [`autocheck`](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize#new-). No need to manually check `status` each time.

Comment: Thanks, now I'm using both 'agent' and 'autocheck' parameters.